# What's the difference between var and quote?

Tags: clojure

What's meaning difference between var and quote in Clojure? For example, `(var a)` and `(quote a)`.

The official site has the below documents, but what's the difference of var object and the value for the symbol? I am confused.

(var symbol)
The symbol must resolve to a var, and the Var object itself (not its value) is returned

Comment: Consider adding in the definition for `quote` as well. It ought to make sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`(quote a)` returns a symbol (clojure.lang.Symbol) - it effectively does the same as `'a`. It's worth reading a bit more about the [Clojure reader](http://clojure.org/reader) to find out a bit more about symbols. Example:

```
(quote a)
=> a
```

`(var a)` returns the var (clojure.lang.Var) represented by the symbol a in the current namespace. You'll get an error if a is not defined in the current namespace. Example:

```
(var a)
=> #<CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: a in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)>

(def a 1)
(var a)
=> #'user/a
```

That's the technical definition - but here's the intuition behind it: a symbol is a name, which can be used to look up a var in a given namespace. A var itself is a kind of reference that can hold any kind of Clojure value. So a symbol identifies a var which contains a value.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
; #'x a reader short-cut for (var x), and 'x is a short-cut for (quote x)
(def x)
(binding [x 1] (var-set #'x 2) (list (var x) (quote x) x))
```

Which evaluates to something like (comments added)

```
(
 #'sandbox177857/x ; the variable itself - was passed to var-set
 x                 ; the symbol x. same as 'x
 2                 ; last value in #'x
)
```

`set!` will take in (among other things) a Var or a symbol which resolves to a global name (`var-set` will only accept a Var). The reason why `(var-set x ...)` wouldn't have worked is that this would have resulted in the value of x being passed in (and not the Var called x).

Hope this helped. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems Var object is an immediate layer between symbol name and its value, is this right?

Comment: @Thomson It is a way of "talking about" a variable with a given name. In C this isn't needed: `x = x + 1;` The first x is a l-value and not evaluated. Thus Vars in Clojure can be more powerful because they can be passed about as values themselves; C would require pointer fun. Also, because a Var is separated from the name in scope, it can be passed around through different lexical scopes which could have their own "x" variable -- yet the Var is always itself.

Comment: Besides, i cannot run your sample program directly to check the result. I got "CompilerException System.Exception: Unable to resolve var: x in this context". But if I add a (def x 3) before the sample, it also generates exception.

Comment: @pst, thanks. Have you fixed it? I still can't run it through simple copy and paste. Still got "InvalidOperationException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: user/x"

Comment: @pst I can run your sample program now. It seems the var should be declared as dynamic, as (def ^:dynamic x)

Comment: @Thomson : right, a Var is an indirection layer. It is a construct for managing state, as are refs, agents, atoms. So a var is a box where a value can be set. The differentiating property of vars is the ability to dynamically bind a new value to them on a per-thread basis (out-of-the-box with clojure <=1.2, after having declared it as dynamic via the boolean :dynamic metadata starting with the upcoming clojure 1.3), which gives "dynamic scoping" to Clojure (as opposed to "lexical scoping" which is the way closures capture values).